# Implement Object-Instance-Model to PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, design-patterns, synchronization, components, propertygrid

I am building a GUI application that will be the front-end for an XML configuration file.

The XML structure defines a set of object instances. That is, type names, and property values that should be instantiated in the consuming application (windows service).

So there are three layers:

```
ConfigurationObject <--> ComponentObjects <--> PropertyGrid
```

The `ConfigurationObject` serializes into the proper XML format for the windows service. The `ComponentObjects` are the same types that are used by the windows service.

The problem I am having is determining the best way to keep all three layers in sync.

My first implementation I would update individual properties when they were changed. However this approach didnt work very well when I need to update complex objects to the UI (Although I believe I know what the problem was now)

My current approach involves using TypeConverters to convert between the `ConfigurationObject` and the `ComponentObjects` which works well until a realized that my current logic is ignoring the `BrowseableAttribute` (since i simply iterate over all the `ComponentObject` properties when converting to a `ConfigurationObject`)

So before I spend anymore time on my current approach I want to be sure that I am on the right track. Is there a simpler approach? IS there some model/design pattern I can use in such a situation?

Thanks,
Karl

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figured out the missing pieces to my problem.

I Created a `TypeDescriptionProvider` for the `ConfigurationObject` this provider was used to map between the `ComponentObjects` Properties and the `ConfigurationObject`'s representation of those same properties.

The `ComponentObjects` were decorated with `TypeConverter`s which converted to and from String's

The real key was to assign the `ConfigurationObject` to the PropertyGrid and not the `ComponentObjects`.